# preg_replace add links around words starting with some-part-of-a-word

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've got this preg_replace in php which almost correctly replaces every word starting with 'exploit' into links:

```
preg_replace('#[\b]?(exploit([^ ]*))[\b]?#', '<a>$1</a>', 'My exploits are exploitable.');
```

I get this:

```
My <a>exploits</a> are <a>exploitable.</a>
```

Which is half wrong, the fullstop should not be linked on the second word. I know I need to replace the above part [^ ] to something like [^\b] but it doesn't work.

I know I can always do i.e [^ .] but it would only work on words ending with space and fullstops, not commas for example.

Comment: `[^ ]*` matches all non-spaces, which includes periods. You wish to use a word placeholder for letters just. Also `\b` does not belong in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

`\b(exploit[a-zA-Z]*)` should do the trick.

Aside: This website is pretty handy for trying out preg_replace: http://www.fullonrobotchubby.co.uk/random/preg_tester/preg_tester.php

Comment: Won't work on UTF-8 words. Here's a better checker btw: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: If you need it to to work with "UTF8 words" (by which I assume you mean Unicode code points) you need to mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`\bexploit(\w*)\b` - more simple....

have fun

[**regexrDemo**](http://regexr.com?35vjq)

**EDIT**

as commented if you want only letters:

`/\bexploit([a-z]*)\b/i`

[**regexrDemo only letters**](http://regexr.com?35vk3)

Comment: yes it does... he is using `[^ ]*` and he didn't say he want only letters. but he can change it to a-zA-Z*

Comment: I guess not - I assumed "word" to mean "thing with letters in". Odd that \w doesn't match hyphens.

Comment: I actually wanted the negative \b on my example. This avoids explaining regexp what is a word?, also UTF-8 compatibility. I thought this would be easy...

Comment: By the way, the above didn't work. This did (for latin only): \b(exploit[\w]*)\b

Comment: it should work for UTF8, it may be a problem with your page encoding try adding `u` at the end => /ui, u for UTF and i for insensitivity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with unicode, you could do:

```
preg_replace('#\b(exploit\pL*)#u', '<a>$1</a>', 'My exploits are exploitable.');
```

Where `\pL` stands for any letter.